# Property undefined in Three JS creating 3D canvas as a class

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a web 3D scene using Three.js, in the hope of better future maintainability I opted to code it as a class

```
export class RenderCanvas {

    #canvas;             // document.querySelector(idOfCanvas)
    #renderer;            // WebgL renderer
    #scene;
    #controls            // Trackball control
    #camera
    // ... other properties 
    
    constructor(){ /* ... */ } 
    startup() { 
        this.#renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            canvas: this.#canvas
        });
        // Other initializations 
    }
    loadGeometries() { /* add models and lights into the scene */ }

    update(time) {
        const canvas = this.#renderer.domElement;
        this.#camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
        this.#camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        // This is for resizing the render area and fit the resolution

        requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
        this.#controls.update();

        this.#renderer.render(this.#scene, this.#camera);
    }

    main() {
        this.startup();
        this.addLights();
        this.loadGeometries(); 

        requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
    }
}
```

And in another script I can just do `let rc = new RenderCanvas();` and `rc.main();`.

But in the `update` method, on line `const canvas = this.#renderer.domElement;`, I received a console error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '#renderer')`.

I thought that by the time `update` gets called, the renderer is already initiated. But the error seems to indicate otherwise. Am I misunderstanding the execution order? Or is there something about scope in Javascript at play here?

Comment: Where is `main` called? How is `#renderer` assigned?

Comment: @Konrad `#renderer` is initialized in `startup` as a `WebGLRenderer`. `main` is called in an external javascript by creating an instance of `RenderCanvas()` and called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue seems to be with the update function you have .. you should do it like on of those two ways :

bind:

```
update(time) {
    const canvas = this.#renderer.domElement;
    this.#camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    this.#camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this)); // Bind the context here
    this.#controls.update();
    this.#renderer.render(this.#scene, this.#camera);
}
```

OR - using arrow function:

```
update = (time) => {
    const canvas = this.#renderer.domElement;
    this.#camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    this.#camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    requestAnimationFrame(this.update); // Context is automatically preserved
    this.#controls.update();
    this.#renderer.render(this.#scene, this.#camera);
}
```

Comment: The arrow function worked, looks like I'm missing the *context*. Thank you!